# Summarize information in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

suppose I have a list:

```
INPUT=[{'id': 1, 'context': 'this is q1', 'content': 'this is ch1'},
{'id': 1, 'context': 'this is q1', 'content': 'this is ch2'},
{'id': 1, 'context': 'this is q1', 'content': 'this is ch3'}, 
{'id': 2, 'context': 'this is q12', 'content': 'this is ch14'}]
```

Convert:

```
OUTPUT=[{'id': 1, 'context': 'this is q1', 'content': ['this is ch1','this is ch2','this is ch3']},

{'id': 2, 'context': 'this is q12', 'content': 'this is ch14'}]
```

What is the easiest way on `python` to perform the above conversion?

Comment: What exactly *is* the "above conversion"?  it's not at all clear what your question is.

Comment: It's not at all clear what is going on here. You appear to be putting all by `'this is ch14'` in the list in the first dictionary' content. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Or are you trying to merge together the lists for dictionaries fo rmatching content? This question gave various ways to merge lists in dictionaries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51097619/removing-duplicates-from-list-of-dictionaries-with-multiple-key-value-pairs-by-c

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Comment: You need to try and explain in more detail what you need to achieve. Look here on how to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Using `itertools.groupby`

**Demo:**

```
from itertools import groupby

INPUT=[{'id': 1, 'context': 'this is q1', 'content': 'this is ch1'},
{'id': 1, 'context': 'this is q1', 'content': 'this is ch2'},
{'id': 1, 'context': 'this is q1', 'content': 'this is ch3'}, 
{'id': 2, 'context': 'this is q12', 'content': 'this is ch14'}]

res = []
for key, group in groupby(INPUT, lambda x: (x["id"])):
    temp = []
    for thing in group:
        temp.append(thing["content"])
    res.append({"id": key, "context": thing["context"], 'content': temp})
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'content': ['this is ch1', 'this is ch2', 'this is ch3'], 'id': 1, 'context': 'this is q1'}, {'content': ['this is ch14'], 'id': 2, 'context': 'this is q12'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you the following solution, short and easily readable:

```
from collections import defaultdict

INPUT=[
    {'id': 1, 'context': 'this is q1', 'content': 'this is ch1'},
    {'id': 1, 'context': 'this is q1', 'content': 'this is ch2'},
    {'id': 1, 'context': 'this is q1', 'content': 'this is ch3'}, 
    {'id': 2, 'context': 'this is q12', 'content': 'this is ch14'}]

# Create first a dictionary:
#     - with tuples (id,context) as key
#     - with the appended contents as value
newDict = defaultdict(list)
for d in INPUT:
    newDict[(d['id'],d['context'])].append(d['content'])

# Convert this dictionary into a list of dictionaries with expected keys
OUTPUT = [{'id':k[0], 'context':k[1], 'content':v} for k,v in newDict.items()]

print(OUTPUT)
# [{'id': 1, 'context': 'this is q1', 'content': ['this is ch1', 'this is ch2', 'this is ch3']},
#  {'id': 2, 'context': 'this is q12', 'content': ['this is ch14']}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
for i in range(len(INPUT)):
    INPUT[i]['content'] = [INPUT[i]['content']]
    print(INPUT[i]['content'])
```